# Proving that ${n \choose k}\sim \frac{(n-k)^k}{k!}$ as $n\to \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

**Question:**

> Prove that $${n\choose k} \sim \frac{(n-k)^k}{k!}$$ as $n\to \infty$.

**Attempt and Ideas:**

I don't have too many ideas but I guess I want to manipulate Stirling's Formula, which is
$$ n! \sim n^n e^{-n}(2\pi n)^{1/2}\quad \text{as }n\to\infty  $$ and is equivalent to $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \left( \dfrac{n!}{n^n e^{-n}(2\pi n)^{1/2}} \right) = 1.$$ I can get rid of the $e^{-n}$ term (hopefully?) by using the fact that $$ e^{-k} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n. $$
However, I have no idea how to get rid of the $(2\pi n)^{1/2}$ term and so I'm really lost.

I have also tried using the definition $$ {n\choose k} = \dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} $$ and dividing by $ \frac{(n-k)^k}{k!}$ but it quickly proved fruitless as I don't know how I can demonstrate that $$ \frac{n!}{(n-k)!(n-k)^k} \to 1,\quad \text{as }n\to \infty. $$ Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(n-k)^k}
= \frac{n(n-1) \cdots (n-(k-1))}{(n-k)^k} = \frac n{n-k} \frac{n-1}{n-k} \cdots \frac{n-(k-1)}{n-k}.
$$

Comment: Oh I see. This follows becasue $\frac{n}{n-k}\frac{n-1}{n-k}\cdots\frac{n-(k-1)}{n-k}$ is equivalent to $ (1+\frac{k}{n-k})(1+\frac{k-1}{n-k})\cdots (1+\frac{1}{n-k}) $ which clearly approaches $1$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$. Thank you!

Comment: Yes! Equivalently, $\dfrac{n-j}{n-k} = \dfrac{\frac{n-j}n}{\frac{n-k}n} = \dfrac{1-\frac jn}{1-\frac kn}$ for $j=0,\dots,k-1$.